# When automating website login using VB, does InvokeMember do something special I need to consider?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to automate a website login with VB. I can get my username/password to fill in, but when I invoke the 'click' on the submit button, I get an auth failure. HOWEVER, when I click the button manually in the webbrowser control, I successfully am able to login as expected.

```vb
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login-submit").InvokeMember("Click")
```

I've tried both of these invoke methods, and they both fail with the same authentication failure.

```vb
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If WebBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri = "http://10.0.0.27/login" Then
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", "username")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "password")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login-submit").InvokeMember("Click")
    End If

    '<etc.>
```

So, like I said initially, the code fails with an auth failure, but if I manually click the button, it works just fine.

Curious as to either if the invoke method does something I'm not accounting for, or if I'm simply doing something silly.

Comment: Re-reading this, I should clarify that I comment out the line of code that invokes the click command, and then I hit the button manually.  So I know the username/password combo is good.

Comment: That's very strange, there should be no difference between clicking the button and "clicking the button".

Comment: @CruleD Yup, that's why I'm here.  Perhaps I'll make a video as proof.

Comment: I don't require proof. I've seen magic before.

Comment: `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login-submit").InvokeMember("Click")` has something wrong. You should specify how/when this code is used and show the HTML you're referring to.

Comment: @Jimi This code is called on document completed.  The only interesting thing in the HTML is this:     <input id="login-submit" type="submit" value="Login" onclick="return doLogin();" disabled/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof doLogin === 'function') { document.getElementById('login-submit').disabled = false; }
    </script>